# how does the compiler choose automatic type conversion method

Tags: c++, constructor

In this code, two methods were used to allow conversion of Y object into X object. compiling by g++ always choose constructor. if constructor is private like  :
`private : Y(const X&){std::cout << "Y constructor...\n" ; }`
conversion is prevented either by operator  or constructor. if constructor is private and explicit
`private : explicit Y(const X&){std::cout << "Y constructor...\n" ; }`
compiler use operator instead. Is it the usual way to prevent auto conversion by making conversion constructor private and what is the rule that compiler use to make such kind of conversion.

```
#include <iostream>

class Y ;

class X {
public:
  operator Y()const ;
};

class Y {
public:
  Y(){}
private : 
  explicit Y(const X&){std::cout << "Y constructor...\n" ; }
};

X::operator Y() const { std:: cout << "Operator Y...\n" ;
 return Y ();
}


void func(Y Y_object) {}

int main() {
  X X_object ;
  Y Y_object ;

  func(X_object) ;
  Y_object = X_object ;
}
```

Comment: What is the output you're seeing in this code?

Comment: `operator Y...`  ,  while the output is `Y consructor` if Y() is not private and not explicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most usual way to prevent implicit type conversion is not to declare conversion operator at all and make the constructor `explicit`. However, if you want to keep the conversion operator, you can make explicit too using `explicit` keyword:

```
class X {
public:
  explicit operator Y() const;
};
```

Comment: I found that explicit operator is c++11 feature as shown in compiling result,  and I was also wondering why compiler choose the constructor instead of operator to make conversion.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a standard, for example if you declare the operator as `operator Y&() const` , and make only one conversion `Y_object = X_object` the compiler will choose the operator only and skip the constructor

Comment: @user3270926 Yes, I was wrong. It always  chooses the best matching conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Conversion functions and converting-constructors designate conversions from the type for which the conversion function/constructor is made to the type that is taken in the parameter. In other words, you are converting from an `X` to a `Y` and *not* the other way around as you said.

When there is a conversion from `X` to `Y`, the compiler considers the best conversion possible through function overload resolution. Since access control is not considered during overload resolution, it is possible for a private conversion to be chosen over one that is public if the private one is a more viable conversion. There can also be an ambiguity between two conversions if they are both equally viable.

---

Calling the function `func(X_object)` requires an implicit conversion from `X` to `Y`. Considering both `X::operator Y() const` and the converting constructor `explicit Y::Y(const X&)`, the conversion operator is chosen because the constructor is marked as `explicit` and therefore only can be called through the direct-initialization syntax or an explicit cast.

```
func(Y(X_object));
func(static_cast<Y>(X_object));
```

These both call the explicit converting-constructor because the argument type of the constructor and parameter matches exactly.

---

The same situation occurs when using copy-assignment to implicitly convert an `X` to a `Y`. The implicit conversion operator is a more viable function than the explicit constructor:

```
Y_object = X_object; // calls X_object.operator Y()
```

If direct-initialization syntax or an explicit cast is used, the converting-constructor will be the best viable function.

---

To prevent an implicit conversion from an `X` to a `Y`, it is best that you give `Y` an explicit constructor rather than an explicit conversion operator. In this case there doesn't seem to be a reason to make the constructor private unless you want to prevent the conversion all together, but if you wanted to do that then simply leave the constructor undeclared.

Comment: as you said compiler may choose the best method for conversion; I think the best way is to provide only one way for conversion. One more thing; I found that declaring  conversion constructor as private don't prevent conversion if operator is declared like `operator Y&() const`. may be it is not standard for compiler to look to constructor first.

Comment: @user3270926 As a said, access control is not considered during overload resolution. It doesn't matter if something is declared private or not, the compiler will still look for the best function to call. Also, there's no order in which the compiler looks for viable functions. It compiles the functions into a set of candidate functions and chooses the best one based on specific rules. There's no preference given to either one.