# How to solve ambiguity between conversion constructor and normal constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

I was looking forward to remove ambiguity between normal constructor and auto-conversion constructor.

as far as I know this ambiguity can be partially removed by declaring normal constructor as `explicit` so compilers will avoid using this constructor as conversion constructor like following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class Integer{
  int i ;

public:

  explicit  Integer (const int _i) : i(_i) {} //Normal constructor
  Integer (const int& ii ) : i (ii) {}        // conversion constructor
  operator int() {return int (i) ;}         // Auto-conversion operator

  friend std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &os, const Integer io ) {
    std::cout << io.i  ;
    return os ;
}

};


int main() {

// Integer io (5); call of overloaded ‘Integer(int)’ is ambiguous error 
  Integer io2 = 20 ;          // conversion constructor
  std:: cout << io2 << "\n" ;
  int i = io2 ;               // auto-conversion operator
  std:: cout << i << "\n" ;
}
```

output :

```
20
20
```

my questions are:

1- Is there a standard way to force using a constructor as  conversion constructor, since there is a standard way to force usage as normal constructor?

2- is it a good practice to use conversion constructor and autoconversion operators, in another words can I ensure that different compilers will use the constructor as conversion constructor in case if normal contructor is not overloaded with conversion constructor ?

My thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need both an explicit and an implicit conversion constructor? Just remove `explicit` if you want to allow implicit conversions.

Comment: @  Mike Seymour  if I remove `explicit` and place only one constructor it works fine. but what about the second question; I understand that auto-conversions are some time decided by compiler according to the best conditions so  dont knowif it a standrad way to use this conversion in compilcated conditions?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Implicit conversions are decided according to the rules of the language, and can include conversion by a non-explicit constructor.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Actually I don't remember a useful code now to more explain my questions , But I had an old question which may be little close to my second question http://stackoverflow.com/a/26408446/3270926.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a standard way to force using a constructor as conversion
>   constructor, since there is a standard way to force usage as normal
>   constructor?

Yes, you omit the `explicit` keyword.

> is it a good practice to use conversion constructor and autoconversion
>   operators, in another words can I ensure that different compilers will
>   use the constructor as conversion constructor in case if normal
>   contructor is not overloaded with conversion constructor ?

If the compiler is standards compliant, then there are no issues here. There's nothing wrong with implicit constructions. They can be quite handy when you're constructing literal arrays of objects and such. Can also be surprising. Use your judgement.

Comment: yes , first part is helpful.  but is there really a standard way for forcing auto-conversion and I also think that auto-conversions are somtimes decided by compilers so  `MSVC++` may act differently from `g++`

Comment: Yes, the standard way is the overload resolution rule. You might find the "Explanation" section of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator helps you understand.

Comment: Yes, I already read the reference. one useful thing is following : `If both conversion functions and converting constructors can be used to perform some user-defined conversion, the conversion functions and constructors are both considered by overload resolution in copy-initialization and reference-initialization contexts, but only the constructors are considered in direct-initialization contexts. `

Comment: Right, I already told you the rule was overload resolution. I don't understand why you're still confused.

Comment: I mad a comment on my answer about an old question  that shows different options choosen by compiler for conversion of objects. some answers said that this conversion depends on compiler decision. suppose I used different compilers. Are they going to use he same options? if you are sure it is yes so it is a standard way but if no so better to avoid this way. So I concerned with the standard and the best practice, but thumbs up anyway.

Comment: as you said using autoconversion is quite handy and useful but if you keep using them is it a good pratice or not?